# Error deploying SSIS projects into Azure SSIS DB using PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, bamboo

I am trying to deploy SSIS projects to Azure SSIS DB using powershell. THis script is running on Bamboo server. I am getting below mentioned error.

> 30-Jul-2019 09:03:18  Exception calling "DeployProject" with "2"
>   argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly  30-Jul-2019
>   09:03:18  'Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  30-Jul-2019
>   09:03:18  PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified." 30-Jul-2019 09:03:18  At
>   E:\bamboo-home-2\temp\139919379-138969217-145721286-ScriptBuildTask-4952971710305912424.ps1:84
>   char:17 30-Jul-2019 09:03:18  + ...
>   $folder.DeployProject($projectfilename, $projectFileConte ...
>   30-Jul-2019 09:03:18  +
>   .~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 30-Jul-2019
>   09:03:18      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
>   MethodInvocationException 30-Jul-2019 09:03:18        +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

Using PowerShell script avaialable at below location:

- [Tutorial: Deploy and run a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-deploy-run-monitor-tutorial?view=sql-server-2017)

> 30-Jul-2019 09:03:18  Exception calling "DeployProject" with "2"
>   argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly  30-Jul-2019
>   09:03:18  'Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  30-Jul-2019
>   09:03:18  PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified." 30-Jul-2019 09:03:18  At
>   E:\bamboo-home-2\temp\139919379-138969217-145721286-ScriptBuildTask-4952971710305912424.ps1:84
>   char:17 30-Jul-2019 09:03:18  + ...
>   $folder.DeployProject($projectfilename, $projectFileConte ...
>   30-Jul-2019 09:03:18  +
>   .~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 30-Jul-2019
>   09:03:18      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
>   MethodInvocationException 30-Jul-2019 09:03:18        +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

Comment: Do you have SSIS installed on the same server where Bamboo is running?

Comment: SSDT for VS 2017 is installed on Bamboo server

Comment: If I were you, I'll find this dll and install it in the GAC

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Where can I get this dll?

Comment: You said you installed SSTD, however, I don't know if it comes with that installation or with SSIS. You can do a regular search in the PC to find if it exists, and  then use PowerShell to add it to the GAC : http://andreyzavadskiy.com/2017/12/30/installing-dll-into-gac-using-powershell/