# How to install this missing dll using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I am trying to deploy SSIS projects to Azure SSISDB using PowerShell. Script is throwing below error:

```
24-Aug-2019 16:08:12    'Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
24-Aug-2019 16:08:12    PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

I am trying to install this missing DLL using this script:

```
  # Load the IntegrationServices Assembly
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices") | Out-Null;
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel, "+
    "Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91") | Out-Null;

  # Load the IntegrationServices Assembly
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices") | Out-Null;
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel, "+
    "Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91") | Out-Null;
```

Can someone please let me know how to install this missing dll assembly file?

Comment: You asked this same question back in July, [Error deploying SSIS projects into Azure SSIS DB using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267037/error-deploying-ssis-projects-into-azure-ssis-db-using-powershell)

Comment: I think you might have an XY problem....

Answer (score 0):

If this assembly were needed by SSIS then it should already be installed on Azure. However, to export it from a system that already has it run the following commands:

```
subst A: C:\Windows\Assembly
dir /b A:\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel\14.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
copy A:\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel\14.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\*.dll .
subst A: /d
```

Then, to install it on the target server use `gacutil`:

```
gacutil /i Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel.dll
```

The DLL almost certainly has other dependencies that will need to be exported and imported in like fashion.